# How to check how many DNS requests my squid server makes?

Tags: caching, proxy, dns, squid

I'm using Squid 3.5 on windows 2012 server and I want to know how many DNS requests my server makes.

*Some more details:*

I suspect it makes a dns query on every request and produces a slightly added latency that could be avoided.

Is there any means of finding out this info? I have tried **squidclient mgr:5min** and it shows how long dns requests take on average, but doesn't show the count.

My dns.median_svc_time reads 0.025624 seconds, and it's fine as long as it caches those responses, but if it's 25 msec added to every request, then this is totally unacceptable.

Comment: did you manage to test this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, squid should be able to give you the info you want via cache manager. It provides FQDN stats and a full IP Cache summary (Which I suspect is more what your looking for)

Have a look at the docs [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheManager/FqdnCache) for the fqdn info and [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheManager/IpCache) for the full ipcache details, it gives details of what they both mean/provide.

You access these via;
http://localhost/cgi-bin/cachemgr.cgi?host=localhost&port=3128&user_name=&operation=fqdncache&auth=

http://localhost/cgi-bin/cachemgr.cgi?host=localhost&port=3128&user_name=&operation=ipcache&auth=